# batch transform xslt xml

Tags: xml, windows, xslt, batch-file

I have been trying to figure out a way to batch transform files in directory using an xslt. I tried xml wrench and a few other software but i need to put all this in a script or batch that i can run as needed.

I have started out with a batch file using raptorxml command line as below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Altova\RaptorXMLServer2013\bin>RaptorXML.exe xslt --input=c:\data\test1.xml --output=c:\data\output1.xml c:\data\test.xsl

file:///c:/data/test1.xml: result="OK" xslt-output-files="file:///c:/data/output1.xml"
```

When I try to put this in a batch file as below, I can not understand a thing of what's going on - can't make out if the script ran or was there any error.. Tried putting ECHO in between but that did not help either. I tried to redirect the output to a log using >log.log but that would just get an echo of each of the lines in the file.. i cant see the value of the variables in the look or how the call to raptorxml is being formed. Any hints or pointers will be helpful - thanks.

Here is my batch file: I run it as `batchxform.bat C:\data\ip`

```
cls
call :treeProcess
goto :eof

:treeProcess
cd %1
for %%f in (*.xml) do (
RaptorXML.exe xslt --input=%%f --output=c:\data\op\%%~nf.xml c:\data\test.xsl
)

for /D %%d in (%1) do (
   cd %%d
   call :treeProcess
   cd ..
)

exit /b
```

After the initial answer/post, I added more logic to call the script from another to process files from all subdirs of the input dirs. Thought of sharing that script here:

```
ECHO OFF
set _xform=C:\Users\gkalra\Documents\work\Annotation\code\batchxform.cmd
rem call _xform %1
FOR /R %1 %%G in (.) DO (
 Pushd %%G
 Echo now in %%G
 rem dir /b "%%G/*.xml"
 call "%_xform%" %%G
 Popd 
)
Echo "back home"
```

Comment: For one you should use `pushd` and `popd` instead of `cd`

Comment: Yep did that for one.. realized that late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save as batchxform.cmd

Asumes inputDir\ip as source of files, inputDir\op as output directory, and inputDir\test.xls as xls

Call as batchxform.cmd c:\data

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    cls

    if "%~1"=="" goto endProcess

    set _inputDir=%~1\ip
    set _outputDir=%~1\op
    set _xsl=%~1\test.xsl
    set _raptor=C:\Program Files (x86)\Altova\RaptorXMLServer2013\bin\RaptorXML.exe

    for %%f in ("%_inputDir%\*.xml") do (
        "%_raptor%" xslt --input="%%f" --output="%_outputDir%\%%~nxf"  "%_xsl%"
    )

:endProcess
    endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks very very much MC ND.. if you don't mind, could you help understand what made your solution work, and what was i doing wrong? is it the path names involved.. i'll try to find out as well..

Comment: Your batch file is not really wrong, mine is simple more organized and (using quotes where needed) is prepared for spaces in file/directory names. Your code tries to recurse the initial directory, processing each subdirectory, probably trying to process what it should not.